# Local copy of database in clients managed by server

Tags: database, wcf, synchronization, client-server, local-storage

I have a database with limited external connections(up to 5). Because of that reason I introduced a server applications which maintains all database operations. That server uses WCF service with callback to inform clients of all changes. Clients store local copy of database in serialized dictionaries. When all works fine then if one client or server perform a change, then all other clients/server are notified almost instantly. Problem is that sometimes client goes out of sync and only way to repair that is to delete local copy of database(sometimes also on server). I figured out that it happens when some objects are deleted from database. I use datetime with auto update to find changed rows, but this doesn't work well with deleted objects. One table has more than 160000 rows, so comparing them with local copy is...troublesome. So question is:

1) Can anybody point me for good algorithm for creating and maintaining local copy of database(between actual database and server, and between server and clients) (I can't use replication)

2) Better way than serialized dictionaries to store it locally.(app takes lots of space when all data is loaded)

PS. I thought about several solutions without database, but I always came to conclusion that I need that local copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Can anybody point me for good algorithm for creating and
>   maintaining local copy of database(between actual database and server,
>   and between server and clients) (I can't use replication)

Easiest solution in your case may be adding `IsDeleted` column to your data tables.
You should not update synchronization process in that case (except adding support for that new column) but you will need to update your SQL queries with "and not IsDeleted = 1" where clause.

You also can use `DeletionDate` and "and DeletionDate is not null" if you want to track when object was deleted.

That approach has restrictions but it may be the most cost-efficient solution for deleted records issue because synchronization algorithms are not affected.

> 2) Better way than serialized dictionaries to store it locally.(app
>   takes lots of space when all data is loaded)

I would use files if storing data in memory is not appropriate. Flat TXT files or XML are not good performers for big data sets. You may use compact RDBMS or No-SQL database. I am not very familiar with No-SQL so cannot advise here. 
MS SQL Compact 4.0 is lightweight enough to be used in your case. You need to copy only several DLLs to client machines to start using it and your MS SQL experience is still applicable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I also thought about such column (status column which could hold also other info) but I thought that extra column would be used only for few rows(lots of unused mysql database space). Unfortunately I will have to use it cause I can't see any other option, unless anybody will post it here.

Do you have any suggestion for question 2 ?

Comment: for deletes, create a tombstone table to store the PKs of the rows that are deleted. and use that table to cascade deletes during sync.